# Passport.js Module, undefined callbackURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, drupal-7, passport.js

After setting up the Drupal as this guide says: [Drupal-passport](https://github.com/mixmarket/passport-drupal) I created a simple simple node app to test how it works.

It doesn't, I get the `InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token` error.

Going through the `strategy.js`, I saw that my callbackURL is logging out `undefined` not exactly sure why. The callbackURL is set in my Drupal app

Also preforming a `curl -i -XPOST http://extranet.local/rest/system/connect/` gives me exactly what I need

Here is my node.js code (keep in mind this is just supposed to test the drupal set up).

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var dStrategy = require('passport-drupal').DrupalStrategy;
var passportDrupal = require('passport-drupal');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var session = require('express-session');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'SECRET' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new dStrategy({
    consumerKey: "emDVp7P2LZFLPcN3cNCjLmrjrhQLnNv6",
    consumerSecret: "mkbc3UYEuUQLNQRwLWo3B8zEk4ZrErKa",
    providerURL: "http://extranet.local",
    resourceEndpoint: "rest/system/connect", // <---- optional. Defaults to `rest/system/connect`
    callbackURL: 'http://33.33.33.40:8888/auth/drupal/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    profile.oauth = { token: token, token_secret: tokenSecret };
    done(null, profile);
  }
));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("This is root");
});
app.get('/auth/drupal',
  passport.authenticate('drupal'),
  function(req, res) {
    // The request will be redirected to the Drupal website for
    // authentication, so this function will not be called.
});
app.get('/auth/drupal/callback',
  passport.authenticate('drupal', { failureRedirect: '/error' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/signedin');
});

app.get('/error', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("Could not sign in");
});
app.get('/signedin', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("signed in");
});

server.listen(8888, '33.33.33.40');
```

Any clues as to why or ideas are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [`strategy.js`](https://github.com/mixmarket/passport-drupal/blob/master/lib/passport-drupal/strategy.js) code of the library [`passport-drupal`](https://github.com/mixmarket/passport-drupal), you will see that the `DrupalStrategy` constructor does not expect a `callbackURL` property in the options parameter object and it also does not pass it further into the `OAuthStrategy`.

This is the code snippet that creates the parameter for the oauth strategy:

```
  // Determine all necessary OAuth options
  var oauthOptions = {
    requestTokenURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/request_token',
    accessTokenURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/access_token',
    userAuthorizationURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/authorize',
    consumerKey: options.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: options.consumerSecret
  };

  OAuthStrategy.call(this, oauthOptions, verify);
```

It should be modified to pass the callbackURL, for example like this:

```
  // Determine all necessary OAuth options
  var oauthOptions = {
    requestTokenURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/request_token',
    accessTokenURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/access_token',
    userAuthorizationURL: this._providerURL + '/oauth/authorize',
    consumerKey: options.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: options.consumerSecret,
    callbackURL: options.callbackURL// <==== THIS LINE WAS ADDED
  };

  OAuthStrategy.call(this, oauthOptions, verify);
```

I'm not sure that will solve your issue though. But I made a [pull request](https://github.com/mixmarket/passport-drupal/pull/3)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating an issue.

Comment: You were mostly right. I am going to ask him to modify his docs. There many things missing.